# How to deal with onStartPrinterStateTracking?

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

The way that Android manage bluetooth printer is - hum well - quite special and not so easy to understand.

I wrote a `PrinterService` and there is something I don't really understand.

The doc says:

> If the system is interested in being constantly updated for the state of a printer you will receive a call to onStartPrinterStateTracking(PrinterId) after which you will have to do a best effort to keep the system updated for changes in the printer state and capabilities. You also must update the printer capabilities if you did not provide them when adding it, or the printer will be ignored.

In fact it seems always interested even if I already declared the printer capabilities, but why not...

Maybe I badly wrote my method as follow:

```
@Override
public void onStartPrinterStateTracking(@NonNull PrinterId printerId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartPrinterStateTracking");

    PrinterInfo printerInfo = findPrinterInfo(printerId);

    if (printerInfo != null) {

        List<PrinterInfo> printers = new Vector<>();
        printers.add(printerInfo);
        addPrinters(printers);

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find requested printer !");
    }

}
```

And so, everytime I want to print and get into the print preview, this method is called.

Problem: `addPrinters(printers);` takes a while and is asynchronous from the spooler management so while it does what it has to do, the print job is started and interrupted in the middle by what `addPrinters(printers);` do internally !!

May I have to delay the print job if `onStartPrinterStateTracking`has been called, waiting the return of `addPrinters(printers);` ?

Comment: The problem is not clear but onStartPrinterStateTracking is called when the user picks the printer and before they tap the print button then you get an onStopPrinterStateTracking call after the print button is tapped, addPrinters doesn't seem to take that long so I'm not sure what the problem is

Comment: @Nonos, In fact I was wrong. I didn't see that I had a disconnection command somewhere in my code. `onStartPrinterStateTracking()` or anything else was not responsible here. Thanks anyway